# Why getting 403 forbidden exception only when deployed on Heroku?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have created a simple controller using spring boot that consumes an API, does some formatting, and redirects to a template.

It worked perfectly fine on local but after deploying on Heroku, the rest of the method works fine except for the part of API call which is giving 403 Forbidden error.

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class ApptController {

    @Value("${code}")
    private String code;
    @Value("${url}")
    private String url;
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String checkAvailableAppt() {

        boolean isApptAvailable = false;
        List<Session> apptList = null;
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36");
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.TEXT_HTML, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        HttpEntity<String> httpEntity = new HttpEntity<String>("parameters", headers);
        List<String> dates = IntStream.range(0, 3).boxed().map(day -> LocalDate.now().plusDays(day).format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy")))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());

        for (String date : dates) {
            try {
                apptList = Objects.requireNonNull(restTemplate.exchange(String.format(url, code, date), 
                        HttpMethod.GET, httpEntity, Sessions.class).getBody()).getSessions();
                if (!apptList.isEmpty() && apptList.stream().anyMatch(session -> session.getWaitingList() == 10)) {
                    isApptAvailable = true;
                    break;
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        // business logic   
        return "index.html";
    }
}
```

My question is what might be the reason & how do I debug this as I am not getting any error on local but only once deployed?
Thanks for any help in advance.

Getting error on that line like:

```
2021-05-09T10:55:16.857564+00:00 app[web.1]: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$Forbidden: 403 Forbidden: [<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
2021-05-09T10:55:16.857573+00:00 app[web.1]: <HTML><HEAD><META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
2021-05-09T10:55:16.857580+00:00 app[web.1]: <TITLE>ERROR... (919 bytes)]
```

Comment: One reason may be that they're blocking requests from Heroku's IP range. Is the API free to use, since you don't seem to be authenticating in any way?

Comment: @Kayaman yes, it is a public api. I am able to access from local and it is giving correct results!